# How to check if two table include the same information in Big Query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

Assume we have a table `table_a` with two string and one int fields:

```
CREATE TABLE `YOUR_DATABASE.table_a` (
  `A1` STRING,
  `A2` INT64,
  `A3` STRING,
);
```

`table_a` includes some data:

```
INSERT `YOUR_DATABASE.table_a` (A1, A2, A3)
VALUES("X111", 10, "2022-02-07 08:19:00"),
      ("Y222", 15, "2017-05-08 10:19:00"),
      ("X111", 0,"2011-08-02 02:30:00"),
      ("X111", 12, "2019-12-20 11:25:00"),
      ("Y222", 258, "2001-10-14 07:00:00"),
      ("Z333", 4, "2015-03-08 03:25:12")
```

We have another table, `table_b`, which is kind of identical to `table_a`. In fact, `table_b` has the exact same fields and values as in `table_a` and it also has an extra DATETIME field. This extra DATETIME field, `B4`, is essentially same as `A3` but converted to a standard DATETIME format.

```
CREATE TABLE `YOUR_DATABASE.table_b` (
  `B1` STRING,
  `B2` INT64,
  `B3` STRING,
  `B4` DATETIME,
);
```

And the values in `table_b` are:

```
INSERT `YOUR_DATABASE.table_b` (B1, B2, B3, B4)
VALUES("X111", 10, "2022-02-07 08:19:00", DATETIME(PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%y %H:%M:%S","2022-02-07 08:19:00"),"America/Los_Angeles")),
      ("Y222", 15, "2017-05-08 10:19:00", DATETIME(PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%y %H:%M:%S","2017-05-08 10:19:00"),"America/Los_Angeles")),
      ("X111", 0, "2011-08-02 02:30:00", DATETIME(PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%y %H:%M:%S","2011-08-02 02:30:00"),"America/Los_Angeles")),
      ("X111", 12, "2019-12-20 11:25:00", DATETIME(PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%y %H:%M:%S","2019-12-20 11:25:00"),"America/Los_Angeles")),
      ("Y222", 258, "2001-10-14 07:00:00", DATETIME(PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%y %H:%M:%S","2001-10-14 07:00:00"),"America/Los_Angeles")),
      ("Z333", 4, "2015-03-08 03:25:12", DATETIME(PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%y %H:%M:%S","2015-03-08 03:25:12"),"America/Los_Angeles"))
```

Note, `table_a` and `table_b` may or may not have a primary key. How can I check if `table_a` and `table_b` include the same information? I have a couple of `table_a` in my database and I have created equivalent `table_b` for each of them; now I want to double check and make sure the tables include same information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM table_a
FULL OUTER JOIN table_b
 on FARM_FINGERPRINT(ARRAY_TO_STRING([A1, CAST(A2 AS STRING), A3],"")) = FARM_FINGERPRINT(ARRAY_TO_STRING([B1, CAST(B2 AS STRING), B3],""))
WHERE A1 IS NULL 
OR B1 IS NULL
```

This process concatenates and hashes the row from each table then returns where there is not a match on each side.

With the sample data provided it yields:
[image]

Comment: I edited the question and made columns ```A2``` and ```B2``` identical. Your solution returns 0 rows which is good as it is what I expected to see. I will further explore this solution and will accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to know whether the tables contain the same data, then you can use `CHECKSUM()`. This basically calculates the cumulative hash for all values in the column and generates a value. If both values are the same, your tables have the same data in those columns.

```sql
SELECT 
    CHECKSUM(A1), CHECKSUM(A2), CHECKSUM(A3)
FROM 
    YOUR_DATABASE.table_a

SELECT 
    CHECKSUM(A1), CHECKSUM(A2), CHECKSUM(A3)
FROM 
    YOUR_DATABASE.table_b
```

More on `CHECKSUM()` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Bear in mind that if you want to check which columns are not equal, you are better off with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` as mentioned by @Daniel Zagales.

**Edit**:
`CHECKSUM()` isn't supported in Google BigQuery, but you can use `FARM_FINGERPRINT()` instead of `CHECKSUM()` instead. So this is what your code would look like:

```sql
SELECT 
    FARM_FINGERPRINT(A1), FARM_FINGERPRINT(A2), FARM_FINGERPRINT(A3)
FROM 
    YOUR_DATABASE.table_a

SELECT 
    FARM_FINGERPRINT(A1), FARM_FINGERPRINT(A2), FARM_FINGERPRINT(A3)
FROM 
    YOUR_DATABASE.table_b
```

More info on hash functions in Google BigQuery can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/hash_functions).

Comment: I'm not sure if google big query support CHECKSUM(). Does it?

Comment: @khemedi you're right. I edited the answer to use `FARM_FINGERPRINT()`.